# Django prepend string to url

Tags: django, url

How do I prepend a string to all my urls?
Say I have http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/new/
I want to have http://127.0.0.1:8000/**username**/articles/new/
Without having to change all the template urls throughout my site.
The string I want to prepend here is **username** based on logged in user.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Is `articles` a separate app?

Comment: Yes it is. There are many more apps as well.

Answer (score 3):

To do it first you have to use the templatetags `url` in all your templates.

If in your `urls.py` you have something like:

```
url(r'^articles/new$', NewArticleView.as_view(), name='new_article')
```

And in your templates you have:

```
<a href="{% url 'new_article' %}">new article</a>
```

Transform it to:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>.+/articles/new$', NewArticleView.as_view(), name='new_article')

<a href="{% url 'new_article' request.user.username %}">new article</a>
```

If you don't use the templatetags `url` you have no other way (in my knowledge) than changing all your templates

Comment: What I am trying to avoid is having to change all the `a href= ` urls in my templates. Your approach demands this.

Comment: Well I gave you the way to avoid rewritting all your urls next time you want to change them.